# How to generate C++ constructor / copy constructor with Eclipse on Mac OS

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, operating-system

Is there any way of generating a constructor / copy constructor with a few clicks?
In Java this is possible. But for C++ there is no option. I've seen a few stackoverflow threads, but I hope in the mean time there is a possible solution for this or a workaround.

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround:

if you want to create a new file, just use the option new Class and then you are able to select "Constructor, Destructor, Move Constructor" and so on...
And if you want to implement them in the .cpp file you can just right click in your header file and go to Source -> Implement Methods.. and it will add them into your .cpp file.